Stable and Pointed Infinity-Operads
I wanted to understand the construction of the maps $\mathsf{An}^{\times} \xrightarrow{(-)_+} \mathsf{An}_{*/}^{\wedge} \xrightarrow{\Sigma^{\infty}} \mathsf{Sp}^{\otimes}$ of commutative algebras in $\mathsf{Pr}^L$. I reckon that this cannot be "too easy" since these objects involve a lot of data and the construction of each is non-trivial.
Nonetheless, following the lecture notes from Hebestreit-Wagner they use certain general adjunction results (p. 130) from the theory of $\infty$-operads. My question only concerns a particular example.
In these notes one constructs the smash product of spectra as $\mathsf{Sp}^{\otimes} = \mathsf{Sp}^{\mathsf{Op}_{\infty}}(\mathsf{An}^{\times})$ where $\mathsf{Sp}^{\mathsf{Op}_{\infty}}(-)$ is a general construction turning left-exact $\infty$-operads into stable $\infty$-operads studied by Thomas Nikolaus.
Question. Is $\mathsf{Sp}^{\otimes} \simeq \mathsf{Sp}^{\mathsf{Op}_{\infty}}(\mathsf{An}_{*/}^{\wedge})$?
At the very least it seem like Hebestreit-Wagner use this in the first line of p. 130 to construct $\Sigma^{\infty} : \mathsf{An}_{*/}^{\wedge} \to \mathsf{Sp}^{\otimes}$.

I'm not familiar with Hebestreit and Wagner's approach, i.e. what precisely $Sp^{Op_\infty}(An^\times)$ is, but it's certainly the case that the "usual" category of spectra, as constructed say in Lurie's Higher Algebra, is equivalent to the stabilization (which for monoidal presentable infinity categories is monoidal) of $An^{\wedge}_{\ast/}$. So unless H & W's stabilization functor isn't equivalent to Lurie's, what you ask is certainly true.

You can also prove this with the results from the lecture notes of Hebestreit-Wagner like so: by adjunction, it suffices to show that $\mathrm{Op}_\infty^{\mathrm{lex}}(\mathcal{O}, \mathrm{An}^\wedge_{*/})\simeq\mathrm{Op}_\infty^{\mathrm{lex}}(\mathcal{O},\mathrm{An}^\times)$ for any stable $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{O}$. Because the $\infty$-category $\mathrm{Op}_\infty^{\mathrm{pt,lex}}$ of pointed $\infty$-operads with finite operadic limits is a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Op}_\infty^{\mathrm{lex}}$, and because $\mathrm{An}^\wedge_{*/}\simeq(\mathrm{An}^\times)^{\mathrm{Op}_\infty}_*$, it hence suffices to show that the adjunction $\mathrm{incl}\colon\mathrm{Op}_\infty^\mathrm{pt}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Op}_{\infty,*}\colon(-)^{\mathrm{Op}_\infty}_*$ retricts to an adjunction $\mathrm{incl}\colon\mathrm{Op}_\infty^\mathrm{pt, lex}\rightleftarrows\mathrm{Op}^\mathrm{lex}_{\infty}\colon(-)^{\mathrm{Op}_\infty}_*$. For this, it suffices to observe that the unit and counit of the first adjunction both lie in the correct non-full subcategories in case we are looking at (pointed) left exact $\infty$-operads. For the unit this is clear since it is an equivalence always, and for the counit this folllows from the statement that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{P}^{\mathrm{Op}_\infty}_*\to\mathcal{P}$ preserves all existing operadic limits, for any $\infty$-operad $\mathcal{P}$ with a terminal object. (This is the direct analogue of the statement that the forgetful functor $\mathcal{C}_{x/}\to\mathcal{C}$ preserves all existing limits when $\mathcal{C}$ is an $\infty$-category.)

As I said in my comment, this is done in Lurie's book Higher Algebra, and I'm not certain how that relates to the Hebestreit and Wagner notes. However, even the relevant results from HA are a bit difficult to assemble, so maybe it's worth writing it out here as a complete answer.
Proposition HA.4.8.2.4 gives that idempotent objects induce "localization functors" by tensoring. A localization functor on an $\infty$-category $L\colon C\to C$, per Lurie's book Higher Topos Theory, has a category of local objects $C_L\subseteq C$, and $L$ is the left adjoint of the (fully faithful) inclusion $C_L\hookrightarrow C$. Recall that the right adjoint of an adjunction is fully faithful if and only if the counit is an equivalence. In this case that means that if we've got an idempotent object $E$ with associated localization functor $L_E$, and a fully faithful inclusion of the local objects $i\colon C_{L_E}\hookrightarrow C$ the $Li X\simeq E\otimes X\simeq X$ whenever $X\in C_{L_E}$. In other words, localizing a local object doesn't change it.
Now we specialize to the case that $C=Pr^L$. Note that Lurie gives a slightly different definition for idempotent objects in a symmetric monoidal category (HA.4.8.2.8) than a monoidal category (HA.4.8.2.1) but by the discussion following HA.4.8.2.8 these are equivalent in the symmetric monoidal case (hence HA.4.2.8.4, which is only stated for the monoidal case, continues to hold). Lurie shows that pointed spaces $S_\ast$ as well as spectra $Sp$ are idempotent objects of $Pr^L$ where, by HA.4.8.2.15, $S_\ast$ is equipped with the smash product tensor product in the usual way. Of course, the category of spaces $S$ is also idempotent, and moreover is the monoidal unit of $Pr^L$.
Okay, so we have localization functors associated to all of these categories, where $L_S$ is just the identity functor. Now you notice that, since spectra is already pointed, you have $Sp\otimes S_\ast\simeq Sp$ and that, therefore, $Sp\simeq Sp\otimes S\simeq Sp\otimes S_\ast\otimes S\simeq Sp\otimes S_\ast$. In other words "the stabilization of pointed spaces (equipped with smash product) is equivalent to the stabilization of spaces is equivalent to the stabilization of the pointing of spaces," or something along these lines.

That‘s nice, thank you! It‘s probably a weakness of Hebestreit‘s lectures that he manages to avoid presentable $\infty$-categories.
